# No se visualiza la View

Tags: javascript, json, mvc, razor

A través de una función de `javascript` estoy pasando un `array`al `controlador`con `JSON`, los datos del `array` me llegan bien al `controlador`, pero no se por qué razón la `view Comprar.cshtml` no se me visualiza. Por el momento en la `view` tengo un titulo solamente, que debería mostrarse. No se por qué razón me sucede esto!.

aca el `boton`que llama a la función Comprar de javascript:

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <div id="miDiv"></div>
            <button onclick="comprar();" class="btn btn-info" id="btnComprar" value="" type="button">Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aca la función Comprar de `javascript`:

```js
function comprar() {

        var uri = '@Url.Action("Comprar", "Usser")';
        var ides = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayId'));

        //compruebo array vacio
        if (arrId.length === 0)
        {
            alert("El carro esta vacío!, agregue un libro.")
        }
        else
        {
             //aca paso el array 'ides' al controlador de mvc usando json
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                data: JSON.stringify(ides),//pasale el arrId de la funcion createUpdatedTable
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
        }
    }
```

Aca el `controlador` recibiendo el `array`:

```html
public ActionResult Comprar(int[] data)
        {
            int tam = data.Length;
            LibroService ls = new LibroService();
            Libro book = new Libro();
            List<Libro> lista = new List<Libro>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
            {
                book = ls.GetBook(data[i]);
                lista.Add(book);
            }

            //ViewData["ides"] = data;

            return View(lista);
        }
```

Y por ultimo la `View Comprar.cshtml`

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>
@using Librery_MVC.Models;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UsserLayout.cshtml";

}

<h1>Hola pagina comprar</h1>
```

Comment: Te falta traer los datos recibidos en la petición de Ajax, mira en la pestaña network y mira lo que sucede cuando le das click

Comment: coloca un breakpoint en `return View(lista);` y dale click, si todo es correcto, se detendría ahí. En este caso, falta agregar colocar tu HTML de regreso de esa vista en la vista donde estás. Vas por buen camino, intenta un poco más y vemos qué sale :D De nada hermano lml

Comment: deja agrego la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los comentarios se ve que tu lógica está casi lista, aquí te dejo lo que hace falta, espero se entienda :D

El HTML

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <div id="miDiv"></div>
            <button onclick="comprar();" class="btn btn-info" id="btnComprar" value="" type="button">Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista">
</div>
```

El JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    data: JSON.stringify(ides),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(respuestaDelServidor) {
      $("#IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista").html(respuestaDelServidor);
    }
});
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax Documentación de jQuery
- https://tutorialesprogramacionya.com Sitio de tutoriales
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Workshop de ASP.net MVC 5 con jQuery, Razor y Entity Framework

Comment: fredyfx! ahora si!..olvide cambiar $("#IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista").html(response) por respuestaDelServidor, mil disculpas. O sea que lo que hiciste fue traerme los datos que tengo en la View Comprar.cshtml a la view de donde estoy parado. es una posible solución y sos un genio! muy agradecido por tu colaboración, pero yo no quiero que me traigo los datos de la view Comprar.cshtml, sino que quiero ir  a Comprar.cshtml y quedarme ahí parado se entiende?